# Formula parse error with AVERAGEIFS in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to calculate averages in a column but only on selected rows, depending on specific values in another column. I see that I should probably use `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS`, but somehow it does not work, not even if I copy and paste the example from Google's help. I did experience the same in multiple browsers and with both versions of the function. What can be the problem?

[image: screenshot of the encountered problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to adjust the formula for your locale?

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A10;B1:B10;">20")
```